# How ro render images from local assets in vue?

Tags: image, vue.js, object, pinia

I have a Vuejs component:

```
<template>
  <CardModel
    v-for="(product, key) in productsStore.products"
    :key="key"
    class="product-card card-model-position"
    :cardTitle="product.name"
  >
    <template #card-content>
      <div class="product-card__sash">-35%</div>
      <div class="product-card__img" style="background-image: url({{product.imgUrl}})"></div>
      <div class="product-card__sale-price">
        {{
          product.salePrice === 0
            ? product.price + ' ' + product.currency
            : product.salePrice + ' ' + product.currency
        }}
      </div>
      <div class="product-card__price">
        {{ product.salePrice === 0 ? null : product.price + ' ' + product.currency }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </CardModel>
</template>
```

In my project, I use Pinia with this implementation:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useProductsStore = defineStore('productsStore', {
  state: () => ({
    products: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'iPhone 6s Plus 16GB',
        salePrice: 649,
        price: 1000,
        currency: '$',
        imgUrl: '../assets/img1.png'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'iPad Pro 32GB',
        salePrice: 600,
        price: 800,
        currency: '$',
        imgUrl: '../assets/img2.png'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'MacBook Pro',
        salePrice: 0,
        price: 8000,
        currency: 'PLN',
        imgUrl: '../assets/img3.png'
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

I want to render all maps and set background image to them from local assets with URL is in object, but I have no idea how to do it.

I tried with many different URL address etc.

Console shows me this error:

`GET http://localhost:5173/assets/img1.png 404 (Not Found)`

I don't know why it doesn't work on localhost...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with function like this

```
const getImageUrl = (assetName) => {
  return new URL(`../../assets/${assetName}.png`, import.meta.url).href
}
```

This function translates url address for every image without the need to import each one.